# Issue with website javascript loading on school server machines

Tags: javascript, web, loading

I have the following website which has a php based /javascript enabled, quiz on it, and that we want to get students to take. It works fine at home, and on the teacher machine, but doesn't work on any student machine at all. There are also other rooms in the school (such as the staffroom) in which it doesn't work, so it doesn't look like a profile issue (As I can access it via my profile and it works from one machine, but not another)

http://www.teachyourselfpython.com/testandtrack/

The issue, as far as I can see, is that the JavaScript is not loading. When you click BEGINNER, it SHOULD load another comboxbox directly underneath it which shows the PRACTICE TEST #1. This doesn't happen for the students.

I have googled this but cannot find a solution. We used Chrome and IE, so that isn't the issue either.

Has anyone had a similar problem, or does anyone have any suggestions as to what the issue may be and how it could be resolved?

As mentioned, the site is:

http://www.teachyourselfpython.com/testandtrack/

Here is the code for the first part of the page, including javascript:

```
<?php 

    require_once("scripts/connect_db.php");

 $rec=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM quizes");

 $user_taken = "";
    if(isset($_POST['user_msg']) && $_POST['user_msg']!=""){
        $user_taken = $_POST['user_msg'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['user_msg']) && $_GET['user_msg']!=""){
        $user_taken = $_GET['user_msg'];
    }



?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Teacher Tracking Python Tests</title>



        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/overlay.js"></script>



        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
        $("#username")
        .popover({  content: "Please enter your unique username and press ENTER to retype it again." })
        .blur(function () {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        });
        $("#school_pin")
        .popover({ content: "Please enter your school pin (this will be given to you by your teacher). For teachers, your username, password and school pin will be given to you on registration.!" })
        .blur(function () {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        });
```

**A useful update:**

**Javascript ES6** was used to write the code, and the developer wonders if this is the problem, as it may not be compatible on older browsers.

The Chrome version I checked (on which it does NOT work) is: Version **47.0.2526.73 m**. I now need to check to see if the teacher machine on which it does work has a different version of browser, even though they apparently use the same deployment package to roll out all browser installations ...

Comment: I use Firefox 57.0.4 (64-Bit). It worked for me.

Comment: @Teemu - right click is disabled, and as I mentioned it works perfectly on certain machines (such as the teacher machine and on all home machines). I have included the code in my question

Comment: @D. Braun - yes, that's the thing, I know it works. It is an issue with it NOT working on a school server ...so what could the issue be? Perhaps someone with experience with working with networks and users on a LAN would be able to shed some light on this

Comment: can't actually fully test because lacking valid ids, but yes form seems to do something both on Firefox and Chrome here. If i understood, the page loads but the form does nothing.. do you have any errors in console (apart from the 404 for 2 resources)? You can access debug tools even without right click by pressing F12.. i suspect a CORS restriction for the ajax calls

Comment: Maybe javascript has been disabled at a domain level? Have you checked if javascript is enabled in IE/Chrome on the machines that it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, the technicians checked and javascript doesn't appear to have been disabled at a domain level (as mentioned, it works fine on certain machines). Also we are using Chrome (javascript autoenabled) so should be fine ......hmm

Comment: @Kaddath, the page loads fine - everything works, except that the javascript bits (so the selection of the combobox and loading of the associated combo box) doesn't work is one example of something not working). CORS restriction for ajax calls - what is that and how can it be resolved?!

Comment: See Q update regarding Javascript ES6 and Chrome Versions which could be the culprit - still not sure

Comment: CORS are a way to set the rights to access to a resource, depending on multiple parameters such as the origin of the call. There are ajax calls to resources, even when you only select the difficulty level. These errors show in the console (open developper tools with F12 on chrome or firefox, and select console tab) when you try to do the call. You should actually report in your question all warnings/errors in the console, because we can't reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Basically, it was down to the version of Chrome and backward compatibility. Javascript ES6 was used to write the code and this simply did not work on certain versions of Chrome while it did on the latest versions.

The Chrome version I checked (on which it did NOT work) was: Version 47.0.2526.73 m. The Chrome version on the teacher machine (which worked) was 61.0.3163.91.

The two solutions are:
1. Upgrade Chrome version (as this was not an immediate option on the network of a school, solution 2 applied
2. Re-write code with older version of JS